# Active Record Scope modifies Active Record Relation. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activerecord-relation

Applying a scope to a an Active Record Relation is permanently modifying the relation. Why?

```
company_purchases.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"purchases\".* FROM \"purchases\" WHERE \"purchases\".\"company_id\" = 17"

company_purchases.by_state("finalized").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"purchases\".* FROM \"purchases\" WHERE \"purchases\".\"company_id\" = 17 AND \"purchases\".\"state\" = 'finalized'"

company_purchases.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"purchases\".* FROM \"purchases\" WHERE \"purchases\".\"company_id\" = 17 AND \"purchases\".\"state\" = 'finalized'"
```

I expect the SQL to look different when called on the scope, but I don't understand why the additional `where` from the scope remains on the next call to `company_purchases` without the scope.

**The scope definition**

```
scope :by_state, ->(state) { where(state: state) }
```

**UPDATE**

This appears to be a bug with the gem Octopus, see here: https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/455

For additional context, the Octopus bug is being introduced because of how company_purchases is composed.

```
company_purchases = company.purchases

# in Company model
def purchases
    Product.using(shard).where(company_id: id)
end
```

Comment: By chance, are you doing something like this `company_purchases = company_purchases.by_state("finalized")`? Just wondering perhaps you have a "search" page with filters... that perhaps you might have unexpectedly stored / overrode the value in the same variable.

Comment: You are right, this behavior is unexpected. The contrived code you provide also would *not* yield these results. Can you provide the *actual* code?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to chime in, see the edited question now. It appears to be an issue with Octopus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Octopus, not Active Record scopes or relations.

See: https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/455

Answer (score 0):

If you `default_scope` than it will display on every query you make on that model. Instead use `scope`  to avoid above problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But I'm not sure if that's what's happening. I've updated the question with the scope definition and it's not a `default_scope` unless I'm misunderstanding your point...